# Write a program that takes a command-line argument n and prints the nth harmonic number using shell script in Gitbash

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

since harmonic numbers include fractions and i dont know how to use fractions in the program , hence i am getting error.
Kindly advise

Below is the program i tried-->>>

```
#!/bin/bash -x

read -p "Enter a number:" n
totalharmonic=0


for((count=1;count<=$n;count++))
do

harmonic=$((1/$count))
totalharmonic=$(($harmonic + $totalharmonic));
done

echo "nth harmonic number is $totalharmonic"
```

Comment: If you have `seq` from GNU coreutils, then this one-liner would do the job: `seq -s+1/ $n | bc -l`

Comment: seq not working on my bash

Answer (score 1):

Don't use bash arithmetic (integer only) for floating point computations. Use for instance `bc` or `awk` or `python`... Example with `bc` and a 10 digits precision:

```bash
$ n=20
$ printf 'scale=10; h=0; for(c=1; c<=%d; c++) h+=1/c; h\n' "$n" | bc
3.5977396567
```

Example with `awk`:

```bash
$ awk -v n=20 'END {for(c=1; c<=n; c++) h+=1/c; printf("%.10f\n", h)}' /dev/null
3.5977396571
```

Comment: Why `awk` instead of `perl` or `python`?

Comment: Endless questions. Why not `awk`?

Comment: Why not [tag:bash]: `for ((v=10**16,to=0,cnt=1;cnt<=n;to+=v/cnt++)){ :;}` ;-)

Comment: Because you're limited to the `bash` integer precision which is rather low (64 bits, I guess). Not mentioning the performance. Floating point (`bc`, `awk`, `python`...) is not the same as fixed point (what you do). Even with double precision floating point you would get much more accurate results than with your method. And `bc` or GNU `awk` are capable of arbitrary precision, they can do even better than regular double precision.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : why `awk` ? cuz it's a bit faster than `perl` (like typically at most up to +10-15%), but way faster than `python` in a wide variety of tasks (sometimes orders of magnitude)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto My remark was a joke. But as you speak about quickness, `bc` is clearly the only choice for this situation!!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : yes and no - most of the time you'll realize the 4 least significant digits reported by `bc` is usually off (when they're to the right of the decimal point), sometimes by quite a bit, no matter what scale you set. my point is simply that with `gawk`, you need get the full amount of precision per the `PREC` value you declared, instead of being a guessing game of sorts

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto See the `bc` documentation and you'll see that `bc` is also capable of arbitrary precision, both for integer and fractional parts. And see also the role of the `scale` parameter.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : how am i supposed to scale `scale=200; y=10; for(x=1; x<200; x++) { y ^= -x^-x^-1 } ` - every value of `x` got back `Runtime warning (func=(main), adr=53): non-zero scale in exponent` , something that `gawk+GMP` was totally fine with providing the results

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto @RAREKpopManifesto First, what you ask for is not defined. For instance, with `x=2`, the expression `-2^-2^-1 = (-2)^(-1/2) = 1/sqrt(-2)` is undefined. Second, arbitrary precision and supported operations are two different things. As the `bc` manual says about `expr  ^ expr`: "_The second expression must be an integer_". So, you cannot use the `^` operator like you do with `bc`, it is not supported. But you can write your own `pow(a,b)` function if you wish with the math library and its `e()` and `l()` functions, and apply it only to **positive** values of `a`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet   ..  bc and seq not working on my gitbash.....  it worked out with awk....        harmonic=`echo $constant $count | awk '{num1=$1;num2=$2;print num1/num2}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
{ sequential integers …… } | 

gawk -v PREC=4096 -M -b -e '
BEGIN { 
        FS = "[ ]"
        __ =   ____^=_=_<_
    ______ = ((_____=(__)(____=_))+(++_))^++_+_--
} {      
     $++NF = sprintf("-%s harmonic-# :::\f\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b%*.*f",
              substr("thstndrd", ( (_+_) * (___=__ % _____) +_\
                                 )^(___~("[" (______)"]")),_+ _), 
                     _____*(++_+_+_)-_,_____*(_+_+--_), ____+=_/__++)

} !(NR % (++_*_++^_+--_+--_*--_*++_*-(++_+_--)+_)*++_____*_____--)'
```

.

```
    19 -th harmonic-# :::
                       3.54773965714368191148376906890838779383671024537898
    38 -th harmonic-# :::
                       4.22790201329535034549100970399459275464696303662619
    57 -th harmonic-# :::
                       4.62901321443235344158004104531631012859838417287837
    76 -th harmonic-# :::
                       4.91451352528988945182286719422645852107180801252460
    95 -th harmonic-# :::
                       5.13634648088877496798633442977633275463363512530370
   114 -th harmonic-# :::
                       5.31779366602824331940489375785429719215436642567080
   133 -rd harmonic-# :::
                       5.47131948062047451388417484204751179174503757003868

   152 -nd harmonic-# :::
                       5.60438205256859124059729492050060940921756955152169
   171 -st harmonic-# :::
                       5.72180034814239078142333334509500384180081954683010
   190 -th harmonic-# :::
                       5.82686900761319639743995851624302267172695962079204
   209 -th harmonic-# :::
                       5.92194035359758723502445031447838958087650057597461
   228 -th harmonic-# :::
                       6.00875267325784672513082218206968917640527973621779
   247 -th harmonic-# :::
                       6.08862692711103503609026975467087326974238667122259
   266 -th harmonic-# :::
                       6.16259049517659562890482737718553187367533415196213

   285 -th harmonic-# :::
                       6.23145820517965413743529012227191413848042900786518
   304 -th harmonic-# :::
                       6.29588720143107560851426403660127825953062935530623
   323 -rd harmonic-# :::
                       6.35641517698583421509773989498468070914781600545073
   342 -nd harmonic-# :::
                       6.41348767779890694488766951049252530102843770918596
   361 -st harmonic-# :::
                       6.46747802533945142692080402716830384029025641361459
   380 -th harmonic-# :::
                       6.51870212999540182472245149948920868711983947931950
   399 -th harmonic-# :::
                       6.56742969117650703400815359615575925873243561407876
```

Comment: Something cryptic! But this won't work on my host, using *`GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0`* !!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : mine isn't that much more advanced than yours :::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::: :::::::::: `GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1) `

Comment: If I run this: `gawk -v PREC=4096 -M -b -e ' ... ' <<<10` , nothing is printed out and result code is `0`!?

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : cuz i only added the last line starting with `! ( NR % …` to print once every 19 rows. change that line to `} 1` and it should work ( and i just re-ran it once to confirm it). most of my code was about the fancy formatting of it. take those out, and the barebones code is much much slimmer

Comment: Hmm... This print `123 -st harmonic-# :::
                    1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (I run Debian 11)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : i dunno what u did to it, but "123-st" immediately is wrong - mine print out `122 -nd harmonic-# :::
                    5.38532947147478767803012133965547380890838198780444
123 -rd harmonic-# :::
                    5.39345955277560068616020264046848193898968280081257
124 -th harmonic-# :::
                    5.40152406890463294422471876950074000350581183307064`
having those `th / nd /st ` is like a form of rapid (though not independent) error-detection

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : i even tested it via `mawk2` instead of `gawk+GMP` - even with less precision, i still got `123 -rd harmonic-# :::
                    5.39345955277560218377175260684452950954437255859375`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246890/discussion-between-f-hauri-give-up-github-and-rare-kpop-manifesto).

Answer (score 0):

#!/bin/bash/

read -p "Enter the number : " n;

hn=1/1;

if [ $n -eq 1 ]
then
echo $hn
else
for ((i=2;i<=$n;i++))
do
hn=`echo "$hn + 1/$i"`
done
fi

echo "nth harmonic number is : $hn"

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!